# Python Mako: Adding a Default Namespace

Tags: python, mako

How can I make a namespace of the form:

```
<%namespace name="foo" module="foo.bar" />
```

available to all of the templates in my project by default; so rather than each template having to include the above line at the start it is just done automatically by mako.  I have looked at the `Template` and `TemplateLookup` class documentation but there does not seem to be an easy way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine inheritance with [Inheritable Namespaces](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/namespaces.html#inheritable-namespaces) to achieve what you want.